# MySQL - search for duplicates

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

RESOLVED!  THANKS EVERYONE.

I need to search for duplicates - table as follows:

```
id, q1, q2, q3, text
```

`id` is unique and I am only interested in finding duplicates where the field `text` is the same.

Any suggestions as I have no idea where to start!

Thanks,

Homer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return you duplicate values of `text`:

```
SELECT  text
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        text
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will return all records having duplicate values of `text`:

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  text
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                text
        HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
        ) q
JOIN    mytable m
ON      m.text = q.text
```

Comment: Brilliant and especially being able to return the records - very much appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

When I do similar things, I usually do a combination of a count query and 'having'.

for example:

```
select 
  text,
  count(*) as cnt
from
  table_name
group by 
  text
having cnt > 1;
```